# BIG QUERY with Anaytycs - table not found when using TABLE_DATA_RANGE

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I amdealing with a simple query from data imported by GoogleAnalytics Premium.

When running this query I get an error, "table not found MYPROJECTNAME:MYPROPERTYID.ga_sessions_ "

```
SELECT 
  trafficSource.source
  , trafficSource.medium
  , COUNT(*) as VisitCount
FROM (
TABLE_DATA_RANGE([MYPROPERTYID.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01') ,TIMESTAMP('2016-05-08'))
)
GROUP BY trafficSource.source, trafficSource.medium
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

What could be the issue?

I really appreciate any help.
Roberto

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

```
SELECT 
  trafficSource.source
  , trafficSource.medium
  , COUNT(*) as VisitCount
FROM (
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([MYPROPERTYID.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01') ,TIMESTAMP('2016-05-08'))
)
GROUP BY trafficSource.source, trafficSource.medium
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

You misspelled TABLE_DATE_RANGE